# Как создать декоратор функции, позволяющий вызывать функцию без использования скобок func = func()?

Tags: python, декоратор

Как создать декоратор функции, позволяющий вызывать функцию без использования скобок func = func()?

```
a = 10
b = 20

def noskob(func):
    def wrapper():
        return func()
    return wrapper

@noskob
def fff():
    c = a+b
    return c

print (fff)
```

Comment: Если бы я такой изврат увидел в проекте - я бы этому разработчику в качестве "награды" дал бы задание заниматься исключительно дебаггингом чужого нерабочего кода в течение месяца :-D

Answer (score 0):

Такой декоратор не получиться сделать.
К тому же это противоречит всякому здравому смыслу.

Comment: @Spatz я с вами не согласен. Я указал на невозможность реализации того, что хочет автор.

Comment: Это фактически не является ответом на вопрос. Если у вас есть другие вопросы, то их можно задать с помощью кнопки «[Задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)». Также, чтобы привлечь больше внимания к вопросу, можно [объявить награду](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/571545)

Comment: @LaravelKensin тот же ответ, что и Spatz

Answer (score 0):

Никак, т.к. как бы вы не обратились к функции, это все равно подразумевает что вы вызовете у нее какой либо метод, хоть и неявно, и вот этот метод надо переопределить.

Например, `print(fff)` это аналог вызова у функции fff методов `fff.__repr__()` или `fff.__str__()`, что подразумевает возврат ими только str значений, в вашем же примере возвращает int, что вызовет ошибку TypeError: **str** returned non-string (type int)

Смотреть это удобнее на примере классов

```
class FFF:
    def __repr__(self):
        c = a + b
        return c

    def __str__(self):
        c = a + b
        return c

fff = FFF()
print(fff)
```

Да и вообще такое использование неоправданно ни при каких обстоятельствах